# Mappping Processor as plugin in spring maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, mapstruct

I develop a project which uses lombok and mapstruct libraries.
I have the following maven structure:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
...

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>1.18.8</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

So far I have not any problems with running up application. Today I recevied the follwing error during compilation.

```
java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException   at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultVersionInformation.createManifestUrl(DefaultVersionInformation.java:180)
```

This is an example usage of MapStruct in my project.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {}, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
public interface AccountMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "registerDto.firstName", target = "firstName")
    Account from(RegisterDto registerDto, PasswordDto passwordDto);
}
```

What could be the issue in that case ?
That problem I have only in IntelliJ. In cmd I can run and compile project.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use old versions of MapStruct? https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor (1.4.1.Final?)

Comment: @khmarbaise for newest version 1.4.1.Final I receive the same error.

Comment: And is there a particular reason you have both MapStruct _and_ ModelMapper?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- just for new experience.

Comment: @maciejka you should update the mapstruct-processor as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an interesting article which solves compilation problem in Intellij.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220430